# laravel post unchecked checkbox with multipul checkboxes

Tags: php, post, laravel, checkbox

I have a number of options within a form, that are saved in a loop after submission. Each of these options includes a check-box, each option has the same checkbox and I'm using the following technique to add the unchecked checkbox value to the POST data:

As I want to know if the checkbox was not checked and get that value.

```
{{ Form::hidden('exclude[]', 0) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('exclude[]', 1) }}
```

However, with this technique the result is that an extra value is added to the array of 'exclude' items.

```
  'exclude' => 
    array (size=10)
  0 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => string '0' (length=1)
  3 => string '0' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => string '0' (length=1)
  6 => string '0' (length=1)
  7 => string '0' (length=1)
  8 => string '0' (length=1)
  9 => string '0' (length=1)
```

In the code this result is taken from there are only 9 instances of the technique above, but once a checkbox is ticked, the value is added to the array rather than replacing it. If I checked the checkbox for every option it would return 18 items in the 'exclude' array.

How can I make it work correctly, as in if its checked, not return the unchecked value as well as the checked. Hope that makes sense :P

Heres an example of whats happening: http://web-4bdd8023-5cb2-4f23-adfa-b08b0b136149.runnable.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to adjust the field names to include an index.

```
// some loop
{{ Form::hidden("exclude[$i]", 0) }}
{{ Form::checkbox("exclude[$i]", 1) }}
```

Comment: Yeah, thought of this just after I posted the Q. Dont need the hidden anymore for it though. :P

Answer (score 0):

I combined answer from @lagbox

```
<?php $counter=0;?>
@foreach ($sales as $salesperson => $name)
{!! Form::hidden('employee_id['.$counter.']',0 ) !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('employee_id['.$counter.']',$salesperson ) !!} {!! $name !!} <br/>
*Alasan Jika Tidak Masuk: {!! Form::text('employee_reason['.$counter.']','',['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'employee_id-field'] ) !!}
<br/>
<?php $counter = $counter+1; ?>
@endforeach
```

not clean enough, but it's working.